# iOS - [WKWebView .cxx_construct] must be used from main thread only

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am new to iOS development.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/webview-ios-tutorial-ios11 to create application with web view. It worked fine, but suddenly stopped and I have no idea what is different.

Now the application is crashing saying: *[WKWebView .cxx_construct] must be used from main thread only* in this code (first line of function):

```
override func loadView() {
    viewerWebKit = WKWebView()
    viewerWebKit.navigationDelegate = self
    view = viewerWebKit
}
```

What is causing this problem? Why did it work fine before? And why did it suddenly stop working?

Comment: Did you make any changes to the project from the tutorial?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything.

Comment: On which device are you running the project?

Comment: Built in simulator, iPhone7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@lokesh's answer is in the right direction, but the wrong solution. `loadView()` appears to be called on a non-main thread. This should never happen. One cause would be that you're calling `loadView()` manually (which you should never do). Another is that you're referencing `view` on a background thread, which you should also never do. (This is the one I suspect you're doing.)

Place a breakpoint in `loadView` before the crash. Run the program, and make sure it's on the main thread. In the call where it isn't, trace backwards to where you're invoking it incorrectly. You should not resolve this by dispatching to the main queue in `loadView`, but you will probably need to add a similar call somewhere else.

Comment: Yes! The second option you mentioned was exactly my problem. I was opening the next ViewController with web view from background thread. I just needed to add DispatchQueue.main.async there, that solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

hi Remember if you want to make UI modifications or creations then it must be done by using main thread only , in your case you did mention that the Ui modifications must be done by main thread only `enter code here`

```
override func loadView() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    viewerWebKit = WKWebView()
    viewerWebKit.navigationDelegate = self
    view = viewerWebKit
  }
}
```

Comment: `loadView` is a method called from the UIKit, it will be called on the main thread. I don't think this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should deal UI in **MainThread**.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
 Some UI code here
})
```